# Service is not defined while testing for angular service using karma/jasmine

Tags: angularjs, unit-testing, jasmine, karma-jasmine

I am trying run following test case using karma.

```
'use strict';

describe('companyService', function () {

    var $httpBackend, companyService;

    beforeEach(module('MyCompany'));

    beforeEach(inject(function (_$httpBackend_, _companyService_) {
        $httpBackend = _$httpBackend_;
        companyService = _companyService_;
    }));

    it('should return a promise for getCompany function', function () {
        expect(typeof companyService.getCompany('foobar').then).toBe('function');
    });
});
```

Following is the Companyservice.js

```
angular.module('myCompany').factory('companyService',
    function($http, MyCompanyApiProvider, $upload) {
        'use strict';

        var _company = null;

        function getCompany(companyId) {
            var x = $http.get(MyCompanyApiProvider.url('companies/' + companyId));
            return x;
        }

        return {
            getCompany: getCompany
        };
    }
);
```

I get an error saying **companyService is undefined** just before calling getcompany method . what am i missing here ?

stacktrace

```
Firefox 38.0.0 (Windows 8.1) companyService should return a promise for getCompany function FAILED
    minErr/<@C:/WebApiRole/bower_components/angular/angular.js:63:12
    loadModules/<@C:/WebApiRole/bower_components/angular/angular.js:4138:15
    forEach@C:/WebApiRole/bower_components/angular/angular.js:323:11
    loadModules@C:/bower_components/angular/angular.js:4099:5
    createInjector@C:/bower_components/angular/angular.js:4025:11
    workFn@C:/WebApiRole/node_modules/angular-mocks/angular-mocks.js:2409:44
    TypeError: companyService is undefined in
    C:/WebApiRole/test/company/CompanyServiceSpec.js (line 15)
    @C:/WebApiRole/test/company/CompanyServiceSpec.js:15:16
    Firefox 38.0.0 (Windows 8.1): Executed 1 of 1 (1 FAILED) ERROR (0.035 secs / 0.015 secs)
```

// Karma configuration

```
module.exports = function(config) {
  config.set({

    // base path that will be used to resolve all patterns (eg. files, exclude)
    basePath: '',


    // frameworks to use
    // available frameworks: https://npmjs.org/browse/keyword/karma-adapter
    frameworks: ['jasmine'],


    // list of files / patterns to load in the browser
    files: [
            'node_modules/requirejs/require.js',
            'bower_components/angular/angular.js',
            'node_modules/angular-mocks/angular-mocks.js',
            'bower_components/ng-file-upload/**/*.js',
            'bower_components/angular-ui-router/release/**/*.js',
            'bower_components/angular-bootstrap/**/*.js',
            'bower_components/angular-translate/**/*.js',
            'bower_components/angular-translate-loader-static-files/**/*.js',
            'bower_components/angular-pnotify/src/**/*.js',
            'bower_components/angular-local-storage/**/*.js',
            'bower_components/angular-loading-bar/build/**/*.js',
            'app/app.js',
            'app/company/CompanyService.js',
            'test/**/*Spec.js'


    ],


    // list of files to exclude
    exclude: [
    ],


    // preprocess matching files before serving them to the browser
    // available preprocessors: https://npmjs.org/browse/keyword/karma-preprocessor
    preprocessors: {
    },


    // test results reporter to use
    // possible values: 'dots', 'progress'
    // available reporters: https://npmjs.org/browse/keyword/karma-reporter
    reporters: ['progress'],


     // web server port
        hostname: 'localhost',
        port: 44455,


    // enable / disable colors in the output (reporters and logs)
    colors: true,


    // level of logging
    // possible values: config.LOG_DISABLE || config.LOG_ERROR || config.LOG_WARN || config.LOG_INFO || config.LOG_DEBUG
    logLevel: config.LOG_INFO,


    // enable / disable watching file and executing tests whenever any file changes
    autoWatch: true,


    // start these browsers
    // available browser launchers: https://npmjs.org/browse/keyword/karma-launcher
    browsers: ['Firefox'],


    // Continuous Integration mode
    // if true, Karma captures browsers, runs the tests and exits
    singleRun: true
  });
};



 Folder structure : 
    |WebApiRole/Karma.Conf.js
    |WebApiRole/app/app.js
    |WebApiRole/app/company/companyservice.js
    |WebApiRole/test/company/CompanyServiceSpec.js
```

Comment: Post the full stack trace of the error / the exact and complete error message.

Comment: @JBNizet I have added the stacktrace above

Answer (score 3):

The service is added to a module name `myCompany`:

```
angular.module('myCompany').factory('companyService',
```

But the test doesn't load that module. It loads a module named `MyCompany`:

```
beforeEach(module('MyCompany'));
```

Comment: i am afraid that is not the issue . I made a slight mistake when copying the code . that is actually the same name i have here (myCompany) in both places . But the problem comes from a different angle

Comment: Then the JS file defining the service is probably not loaded by karma. Edit your question and show the directory structure of the project and the karma configuration. And don't make the same mistake again. Post the real thing.

Comment: added the karma.conf.js file and the folder structure

Comment: You asked karma to load `app/company/CompanyService.js`. Your file is named `app/company/companyservice.js`.

Comment: Thanks . but it is not the cause for this issue .